# Fill remaining vertical space using only CSS when elements wrap using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a responsive view without the use of a media query. The layout of my view has a content div and a footer div. The footer div should always be fixed at the bottom of the view, and the content div should expand vertically to fill the remaining space.

Within the content div will be a left div and a right div. When the width of the view is small, the left div should stack above the right div to form a single column layout. [Here's a screenshot of the single column layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kwSc.png). After some defined width, the right div should move next to the left div to form a two column layout. [Here's a screenshot of the two column layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVMyX.png).

The issue I'm having is when we're in a single column layout. The right div should expand vertically to fill the remaining space of the content div. That means, regardless of the height of the view, the height of the left div should be large enough to only contain its contents and the height of the right div should expand vertically to fill the remaining space. [Here's a screenshot of the desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA6rI.png). However, that's not the behavior I am seeing. [Here's a screenshot of the current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxI1n.png).

My current approach is to use Flexbox, but using any combination of `align-item`, `align-self`, and `align-content` doesn't achieve the desired behavior. I'm currently using `align-self: flex-start;` on the left div to overwrite the default stretch behavior, but the right div doesn't want to expand vertically to fill the remaining space; Flexbox seems to be allocating space for the left div when it shouldn't.

Thoughts? [Here's a link to the CodePen](https://codepen.io/digoramma/pen/ZEOrJdV).

```css
#editor {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

#footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#leftPane {
  flex: 1 500px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: green;
}

#rightPane {
  flex: 1 750px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="leftPane">
      <p>This element should expand vertically to fit its contents</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightPane">
      <p>This element should expand vertically to fill all remaining space</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>This is the footer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Media queries are an essential part of flexbox. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve without them.

Comment: I agree, but media queries don't work in our particular use case as this could be hosted as part of a larger view.

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen (in Chrome) seems to behave the way you want based on your description, I'm confused as to what's not working?

In IE11 (which doesn't run codepen) you can still use dabblet.com. Your snippet breaks there, but if you change `#editor` to be `display: block;` and set `p {margin: 0; padding: 1rem;}`, it works.

Comment: As you increase the height of the editor, there's space being allocated that neither the left div or right div occupy. The height of the editor won't necessarily be fixed, so although we allocate a minimum height of 500px for the right div, we want the height of the right div to change as the height of the editor changes. I made the editor resizable so that scenario can be tested.

Comment: Looks like you should just be able to set `#rightPane { min-height: 100%; }` ?